# How can I properly set a flag to cause other threads suspended in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

I am just learning multiple threading in java, and I got a question like below.

10 threads are running a same piece of code, then they will do a test periodically. So when a thread is running the test, it will set a flag to suspend other working threads. Then the test needs to wait until all current working threads to finish their work. Once the test is finished, other threads can resume.

Now, I have my structure like this:

```
//this is in run(), so every thread will run the below code
//shared variables between threads. 
//int count=0;
//boolean[] ifworking = new boolean[10]; initially set all to false
//boolean flag = false;
//int numtest = 0;

public void work(){
   int id = (int)Thread.currentThread().getId(); //get current thread id
   ifworking[id] = true;                         //indicate this thread is working
   while(true){
       if(!flag && numtest == 0){
       //do the work
       ifworking[id] = false;                    //indicate this thread is done
       break;
       }
   }
   if(++count%10 == 0) dotest();
}

public void dotest(){
  flag = true;                                  //shows a thread wants do test
  numtest++;                                    //count how many threads doing test
  while(true){
    int ifcantest = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      if(!ifworking[i]) ifcantest++;
    }
    if(ifcantest == 10){
    //do the test code 
    numtest--;
    flag = false;
    break;
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently this code is not that efficient, it has deadlocks, and sometimes when a thread is testing, other threads will be working at parallel, then the test is not accurate.
So can anyone help me to modify that code? I need the 10 threads doing the work at the same time, and if any thread finish the work, it will wait others to finish and then test. Also, 10 threads could doing test at the same time, once no thread is testing, the threads resume to work.
This run() will keep running the process.

Comment: Do you want only one thread to run on `work()` at a time ?

Comment: @AmanArora No, I want the 10 threads to run on work() simultaneously. Then if there are some threads finish on work() and they want to do test, they have to wait other threads to finish their work and suspend them, then they can do test() simultaneously. The other threads can resume until test has been finished.

Comment: You want all the threads to first finish `work()` and when all of them have finished work,then all of them should start `doTest()`? Have i understood you right ?

Comment: @AmanArora Yeah, and maybe not all threads want to start doTest(), some threads will doTest. Then when the threads finish doTest(), all threads resume, they will rerun the work().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. I add a semaphore for that. The code is like below:

```
   Private semaphore flag = new semaphore(10);//create a semaphore which contain 10 permits

   public void work(){
       flag.acquire();                        //acquire one permit
       //do the work
       flag.release();                        //release the permit
   }
   if(++count%10 == 0) dotest();
}

public void dotest(){                              
  while(true){
      if(flag.tryAcquire(10)) break;         //try acquire all permits. If true, all
                                             //the work threads will be blocked;
    }
    //do the test code 
    flag.release(10);                        //when test finish, release all permits,
                                             //then all blocking threads can resume.  
  }
}
```

This method allows working threads running at the same time, and when any thread wants to test, it will wait until all others finish the work. Then it can block all threads that want to work.

Comment: That works like a R/W lock. Why do you implement it yourself? I already told you there is one in the JDK and how you can use it for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need a read-write lock. With that [pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) some tasks considered as reading tasks (working in your case) can be executed in parallel but there is at least one task considered writing (testing in your case) that can't be run in parallel with other tasks.

You can easily do that in java with the help of a [this class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: Yes, that might work for me. But if I want it more efficient, it probably will be a multiple writer and multiple reader case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronize on the object which has the functionality executed by threads. Else you can define your own lock.

Comment: synchronize only allows one thread to do the job, but actually I need them working at the same time.

Comment: Once a thread moves out of the synchronized block one of the blocked thread will get to access the block. From your description you can use [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)